# How can I use a different web.config file for each Azure deployment slot?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have several Azure deployment slots: dev, staging, production, etc.

I want to create a set of web.config files, one for each deployment slot. So web-dev.config, web-staging.config, etc.

I do not want to use the slot-specific settings in Azure because if you have more than one or two settings it seems vastly easier to just have all your settings in a text file.

I do not want to write XML transforms on a single web.config file because that is insane. Config files already have enough complexity without an extra layer of indirection. And even if I didn't think that, web.config transforms seem to be tied to build configuration and not to a deployment destination. I don't want to contort my build process for the benefit of my deploy process.

I know copying and pasting config settings across files is gross but here we are. Until someone at MS fixes configuration in ASP.net, I just want to have one file for each deployment destination and call it a day.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options.

The most obvious is the [transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I don't know why you're so quick to discount it: only a few settings should be changing between environments, right?

Or you can have multiple .config files and then make it part of your deployment script (I hope you're not just using VS to deploy). Your scripts can select the correct file and rename it to web.config.

And of course, you can move all the app settings and connection string stuff, and probably more, out of the web.config file and use alternative configuration systems. Perhaps a giant XML or JSON file with all the settings for each environment in it. Or perhaps use environment variables.

Really, it's up to you to write your deployment scripts and set your configuration up how you want it. It's not "up to Microsoft", it's up to you, though they have made it even easier to use a common configuration system across multiple sources in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: What is wrong with using VS to deploy? I'm the only person working on this project and developing my own battery of deploy scripts seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky Because VS is limited. And it's not reinventing the wheel to use custom deployment scripts. In fact, Microsoft encourages you to do so. Some things you might want to do: check files into source code control, run unit tests, notify you if build tests fail, modify configuration files, copy files up to Azure, notify you if the copy doesn't work, execute migrations, obtain NuGet or Bower packages, compile LESS, SASS, CoffeesScript or TypeScript, minify JS and CSS files, notify you when deployment has completed.

Comment: Those sound to me like very common tasks, which I think is your point. My point is that it seems like a huge waste of effort then if everyone writes their own code to handle those tasks. In my quest for maximum productivity as a one-man team, deployment has been an enormous time-suck for something that is basically an xcopy.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky Everyone has a different deployment use case. Your needs won't match mine, and mine won't match anyone elses. Which is why custom scripts make so much sense. It gives you complete control over your deployment. What's more, it doesn't take much effort. You can copy someone else's script that you find on the Internet and modify it to suit your needs. Just do a web search for "Azure deployment script". Or if you know how to write Powershell (I don't) or Windows command files, you can do that too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! For the moment I decided to make my own config class that wraps a giant hashtable of settings for different environments.

Comment: follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147825/how-to-set-different-authentication-settings-for-different-deployment-slots-for

Comment: @JohnShedletsky I am in total agreement with you. We have been using MS Release Management tool to deploy to our dev, test & prod enviroments. The settings for each stage is stored withing Release Management and is not accessible by the devs thus creating strong security. I don't get why Azure allows you to have "AppSettings" but the rest of the web config is ignored.  What about SMTP settings, WCF endpoint settings, etc... that are stored in the web.config.  It just seems like half a job. I am probably going to use a parameters.xml file for the job. It's used to change web.config on build